# Profiling Django Startup Memory Footprint

Tags: python, django, memory, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my Django 1.8 project's memory usage, and I have noticed that even from initialization, it's using 80+MB, which seems excessive. I observe this when I simply run `./manage shell --plain`. By contrast, an empty Django project on startup uses only 30MB. I want to know what's consuming so much memory.

I have tried various things to reduce memory consumption, including a fair amount of stripping down of the project by removing its apps and URLs. I tried poking around `gc.get_objects` but it's not comprehensible. I got excited about `tracemalloc` so I build a custom Python 2.7.8 with `tracemalloc` included, only to realize that it won't start tracking until I call `start()` from the prompt, at which point the memory has already been consumed.

Questions:

1. What kinds of things could be causing this high memory floor?
2. What process can I use to determine the consumer?

And yes, I realize the versions badly need upgrades. Thanks!

**UPDATE #1**

I did manage to get some use of out `tracemalloc`. I inserted the import and start at the beginning of `manage.py`.

```
/Users/john/.venv/proj-tracemalloc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zinnia/comparison.py:19: size=25.0 MiB (+25.0 MiB), count=27168 (+27168), average=993 B
/usr/local/tracemalloc-py2.7.8/py27/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py:37: size=3936 KiB (+3936 KiB), count=9581 (+9581), average=420 B
...
```

It did reveal one interesting thing - this first line s a blogging app. This loop seems to use a lot of memory, although I guess it's temporary. By line 3 everything is 1.5MB and smaller.

```
PUNCTUATION = dict.fromkeys(
    i for i in range(sys.maxunicode)
    if unicodedata.category(six.unichr(i)).startswith('P')
)
```

**UPDATE #2**

I went through the tedious process of uninstalling packages, apps, and fixing broken code. In the end, it looks like maybe 10MB was due to my internal apps, and 25MB was due to the Django debugging toolbar. This got me down to 45MB.  It doesn't seem unreasonable for my core app to be using up 15MB, taking it down to the 30MB core.  I don't use the toolbar in production, but it definitely needs additional memory for actually working.

In the end, I didn't learn much, but at least nothing seems insanely wrong. I was disappointed with `tracemalloc`, but hopefully it will work better as integrated into Python 3.

Comment: don't worry about memory, django keeps it optimized

Comment: can you share your settings.py?